# How to sink more current than specified?

Tags: transistors, current-source, led-matrix, current-sink

I am using the `TLC5940` ([datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5940.pdf)) in an upcoming project to control the cathode side of an LED matrix, but each of my LEDs needs `70mA` of current. If more than one led in a given column are on at a time then that will end up being `70mA*n` where n is the number of LEDs in the column that is on. The problem is that the `TLC5940` has a maximum current sink of `120mA`. Is there a way to sink the current somewhere else while also using the `TLC5940`?

I was thinking about using a PNP transistor of some sorts but I have no idea about how that would work.

The essentials of my circuit (sorry it is so crude but it includes everything necessary):
[image: Crude Schematic]

Note: This is just two rows and one column of the led matrix.

The problem is not an issue if either A, B, or C send 70mA of current, but if any two or three of those are on then there is too much current.

Comment: What is the size of your dot matrix? Do you have a specific model, datasheet?

Comment: @EdinFifić I am creating my own dot matrix, 8 by 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sink current so the transistor has to be on the low side so PMOS and PNP devices are at a disadvantage. Instead, use an logic-level NMOS or NPN driven by an inverter to fix the logic levels.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7SQHl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The TLC5940 outputs are open-collector so they can only pull the line LO, not HI. So R1 exists to pull the line HI since the inverter is expecting an actual HI or LO input. The inverter is there to correct for the logic level from the TLC5940 output since the the NMOS conducts when a HI gate signal is supplied but you need it to conduct when the TLC5940 outputs a LO.

You may also modify by replacing the NMOS with an NPN and adding a series base resistor.

You may also replace the inverter with a PNP/PMOS that pulls the gate of the NMOS HI and a resistor that pulls the gate of the NMOS LO. But you need to pay attention to voltage levels here so that the PMOS works properly. But since this is an LED matrix I do not recommend this since it just means more discrete parts. You can get many inverters in a single IC.

Comment: Since OP is driving LEDs and current is probably gonna go up as they add more, I would use a power FET, like IRF630 (maybe overkill). I would also move R1 to the input of the NMOS as a pulldown because power FETs have high gate capacitance that needs to be discharged. You might also want to replace NOT1 with a POWER FET driver like the 4427 since it is designed for this, where 7400 or 4000 series gates are not (no pun intended).

Comment: @PeterT As long as the Power FET driver is of the inverting variety. You need to have a pull-up resistor at at the output of the TLC5940 though since the TLC5940's outputs are open collector.

Comment: Oh, yes, good point(s). I thought it was an MCU. (And the 4427 is the non-inverting version, I think the 4427A is the inverting version.)

However, I just read the 5940's datasheet, and it appears both of our solutions break the 4,096 step current control though, assuming OP is using that feature.

Comment: @PeterT Yeah I saw that too. If the OP wants to use that...then things just got really, really complicated. OP will have to have external means of current limiting and set the constant current driver in the TLC5940 to a low value...just enough pull the output down for the inverter or gate driver or whatever.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thank you for the quick answer, I will accept the answer as soon as I test it out. I am not going to use the 4096 step current, I am only going to do on and off to make my life easier. Just a question to clarify, the triangle in your schematic is ground? and current is flowing through the load to the N-channel Mosfet to ground? Thanks again

Comment: @JaredCohen Yeah on both. The downward pointing triangle is ground. Sometimes it is 3 narrowing lines instead of a triangle.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks

Comment: @DKNguyen I was doing some thinking and I realized that I could have about 12 rows on at a time to get about 1A of current. Since this is so low, does it make sense to just use a BJT over a NMOS?

Comment: @JaredCohen Different people prefer different things. I prefer NMOS because zero steady state drive current. Some people prefer BJT because they say it's a bit cheaper (not sure if that is still true) and you don't need to worry as much about drive voltage.

Comment: @DKNguyen is it possible that I just replace the TC5940 with a shift register? and have the output go directly towards the NMOS? I know the question asked originally about using it but Im in the theory stage of the project and just trying to figure out what works best

Comment: @Jared You could but your voltage blocking and current will be limited unless you use external transistors. Your LEDs will also cascade during an update which may or may not be too fast to see.